# How to return full set of child nodes based on search of XML file

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am trying to search an XML file of the following structure:

```
<Root>
   <Record>
      <Filenumber>12314123</Filenumber>
      <StatusEN>Closed</StatusEN>
      <StatusDate>02 Nov 2019</StatusDate>
   </Record>

   <Record>
      <Filenumber>0678672301</Filenumber>
      <StatusEN>Closed</StatusEN>
      <StatusDate>02 Nov 2019</StatusDate>
   </Record>

</Root>
```

I want to search based on the filenumber, but return all 3 nodes and values for the match.

I am trying

```
$q = '12314123';
$file = "status.xml";

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->Load($file);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = "/Root/Record/Filenumber[contains(text(), '$q')]";
 $entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {

     echo $entry->parentNode->nodeValue  ;

  }
```

This seems to return all the *values* I want but in one single string. How can I return them as separate variables or even better, in an array or JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOMNodeList` or `DOMNodeElement` don't know how become an array. And that's why we must do it with our hands:

```
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($entry->parentNode->childNodes as $node) {
        $result[$node->nodeName] = $node->nodeValue;
    }

    var_dump($result);
}
```

Comment: You're a star. I was actually using this approach in an early attempt but was combining it with simplexml which bombed out as soon as I introduced it to my (large) XML file. Thanks.